# How do you access attributes of an object queried from Mongo in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm pretty new to mongo in the Meteor.js framework. Here, I've queried a MongoDB object using it's ID. I'm trying to access an attribute "mana" but it returns me undefined.

```
var skill = Skills.find({_id:Session.get("selected_skill")});
  alert(skill);//This returns me "undefined"
  Skills.update(Session.get("selected_skill"), {$inc: {mana: 1}});
```

Could you enlighten me on the requirements of accessing attributes in mongo for meteor? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` method returns a cursor, not object nor array. To access object, you need to either fetch it from the cursor

```
var skill = Skills.find(Session.get('selected_skill')).fetch()[0];
```

or get it directly with `findOne`:

```
var skill = Skills.findOne(Session.get('selected_skill'));
```

Then you may use it just as any other js object:

```
console.log(skill.mana);
skill._cache = {cooldown: true};
```

---

Keep in mind that on client-side, collection methods like `find` are non-blocking. They return whatever Meteor has in cache, not necessarily what is in the server-side db. That's why you should always use them in a reactive context, or ensure that all data has been fetched before execution (don't worry about the latter until you're fluent with Meteor, start with the first way).

Also, you need to keep in mind that because of this, `findOne` and `find.fetch` may return `null` / empty array, even when the corresponding element is in db (but hasn't been yet cached). If you don't take that into account in your reactive functions, you'll run into errors.

```
Template.article.slug = function() {
    var article = Articles.findOne(current_article);
    if(!article) return '';
    return slugify(article.title);
};
```

If we didn't escape from the function with `if(!article)`, the expression `article.title` would raise an error in the first computation, as `article` would be undefined (assuming it wasn't cached earlier).

---

When you want to update the database from client side, you can alter only one item by a time, and you must refer to the item by its `_id`. This is due to security reasons. Your line for this was ok:

```
Skills.update(Session.get('selected_skill'), {$inc: {mana: 1}});
```

---

`alert()` is a function that *returns* undefined no matter what you feed it.

```
alert(42); // -> undefined
```

Generally, it's **far** better to debug with `console.log` than with `alert`.

Comment: Thanks Hubert!! This has been really helpful for retrieval. Would you also happen to know of ways to connect to Meteor's Production DB using an external sql query tool?

I'm not looking at command level editing in this case

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, especially explaining that `.find` gives a cursor while `.findOne` doesn't