# how to retrieve the "title: my title" value from the mongodb in meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Im creating a blog app using meteor,blaze, Mongo.
i already had add post function, and now i'm creaating a edit post functionality. what i want to achieve is to retrieve the title and content to my edit post modal title and content field so i cant edit all text in the field.

Template.html

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{title}}" placeholder="Title">
```

my solution is to create a method helper name title and insert it in the input value. so that the edit post modal will get the previous value from the add post. so i can edit it

this is my Template helper

```
Template.editPost.helpers({
   title(){
    var title = Posts.find({id: this._id}).title;
    return title;
}
```

});

but nothings happen. i cant retrieve the title values from mongo.

Comment: You want `.findOne()`. The `.find()` method returns a "cursor", and intended for "more than one" result without getting into it. Just use the prescribed method for a single result instead.

Comment: Still not working... is this the right way of grabbing values from the Posts collection? " Posts.find({id: this._id}).title; "

Comment: Why would the code you are presently be right when it's different to what [the answer you are meant to be reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711135/how-do-you-access-attributes-of-an-object-queried-from-mongo-in-meteor) is showing you? Big obvious box above your question for a reason.

Comment: findOne does not make any diffrence. cant still retrieve the title inside the post collection